# L6-30R with L5-20P Devices

Tags: voltage, power, amperage, watts, conversion

My computer lab just got a power upgrade, now we have 208V/30A with L6-30 receptacles, in addition to what we previously had.

I have some leftover rack mounted power distribution units (PDUs) given to me by a partner lab, which have L5-20 plugs (rated for 125V/20A)

Is it possible for me to have my L5-20 devices work off of L6-30 receptacles? I found splitters online that allow me to go from L6-30P to (2)L6-20R, which will fit the L5-20 plugs but I will still be plugging a 125V rated device into 208V socket. Or should I just abandon the L5-20 devices and purchase new L6-30 PDUs? Or should we go back through and change the receptacles to L5-20?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should ask this in the DIY/Home improvement section - there are several people there who are very knowlegeable about the Electrical Code.

Comment: NO, do not plug something rated for 120 V into 208 V. It *will* blow up. It's not a matter of plugs and receptacles, just of voltages.

Comment: L6-30 is rated for 250 V,  not 208. That type of receptacle don't have neutral pin. How you expecting to get 120 V?

Comment: @Hearth, it may not blow up ,  because some power supplies work in wide range of voltages. It is about safety. Installing GFI protection may help, but it may be complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Decided on purchasing L6-30P PDUs, which is what I was expecting. The L520P PDUs were given to me by the partner lab because they also don't have a use for them, because they are also using 208V/30A on L6-30R.

I'll probably save the L5-20P PDUs because there isn't a point in throwing out perfectly good equipment, even if I have no use for it at the moment. Maybe I will request a L5-20R if we need more 125V/20A outlets.